# Create custom shape with html elements

Tags: html, css

I need to create this shape :

[image]

The bounds are not clear in this picture but in real this is regular curve.
The inner circles are my inner elements.
I have some challenge with implementing this element :

- I useed `<div>` and i can't the top border with border-radius and any another method.
- Used `<div>` and set `background-image` for it but i have problem in bounds and i want to change mouse cursor exactly in element bounds.
- I used `<img>` and set `<map>` and `<area>` for it for setting my bounds but i have problem with my inner elements.
- Finally i used HTML5 and canvas element but for inner elements,the circles , i can't find any regular solution.it's very important the bounds for element

How can i implement this object?

Comment: Would [this be of any help?](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much use HTML5 Canvas. From your question I read you cannot determine the bounds of the circle to change the cursor. Detecting whether cursor is inside a circle is pretty easy actually. You'll definitely have the x,y positions of the center of circle along with the radius right ? So all you need to do is check if the distance between the cursor's x/y coordinates and the center of the circles is less than (or equal to) the radius or not. If yes, then it's inside the circle, else it's outside :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, first of all,if i use canvas, how i can create the inner elements?after that , could you get me a sample?

Comment: prepare a big array with objects that holds the x/y positions of the circle along with radius. You can do this manually or think of an auto generating algorithm. Then iterate over it and use the `arc` method to draw all circles. When the mouse is over canvas loop over all the objects in the master array of circles to do the collision (of cursor with circle) checking.